# Magento 2: Swatches property to resize from CSS

Tags: magento2

If I want to show smaller size of swatches on the category page and bigger on view page, when I am applying style it changes on both pages, can anyone guide me how to do this?

```
<i have tried applying style on custom style sheet>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding style with body class. It would be different for both pages..

Comment: no can you tell me class?

Comment: could you share the code where you added style for the swatch.. I will update that..

Comment: for category page add,  body.catalog-category-view .your-swatch {/* Your style*/}

Comment: For product page add, body.catalog-product-view .your-swatch {/* Your Style*/}

Comment: yeah got from this thank you @aravind

Comment: is it working ?

Comment: yes, perfectly working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for category page add,

```
body.catalog-category-view .swatch-option {/* Your style*/}
```

For product page add,

```
body.catalog-product-view .swatch-option {/* Your Style*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit `app/design/frontend/{Package}/{themename}/etc/view.xml` file for change swatches image size.

```
<media>
    <images module="Magento_Catalog">
        <image id="swatch_image" type="swatch_image">
            <width>30</width>
            <height>20</height>
        </image>
        <image id="swatch_thumb" type="swatch_thumb">
            <width>110</width>
            <height>90</height>
        </image>
        <image id="swatch_image_base" type="swatch_image">
            <width>30</width>
            <height>20</height>
        </image>
        <image id="swatch_thumb_base" type="swatch_thumb">
            <width>110</width>
            <height>90</height>
        </image>
    </images>
</media>
```

After the changes, run below commands.

```
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
```

EDIT:

With CSS:

> For Category page side bar:

```
.catalog-category-view .filter-options .swatch-option {
    height: 20px;
    min-width: 30px;
}
```

> For Category page product listing:

```
.catalog-category-view .product-item .swatch-option {
    height: 20px;
    min-width: 30px;
}
```

> For product details page:

```
.catalog-product-view .product-info-main .swatch-option {
    height: 20px;
    min-width: 30px;
}
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: it changes on both pages

Comment: I've updated my answer as per your requirements.